# Oracle ADF: How to filter out rows in RichTable?

Tags: oracle-adf

I have following requirement.

1. Display data in a table
2. Clicking on checkbox filter out currently displayed rows by some condition
3. Clicking on checkbox once again return data appearance to it's previous state

To achieve this I've ovverided method rowQualifies in my ViewObject which is simple SQL based view object to apply my custom filter logic.

When user clicks on checkbox I refresh view object data to apply filter

```
viewObject.setDoFiltering(true);
viewObject.setQueryMode(ViewObject.QUERY_MODE_SCAN_VIEW_ROWS);
viewObject.executeQuery();
```

It works perfectly, data set updates without interacting with database and my custom filter logic applies as well.

But when I need to cancel filter it wouldn't work because iterator doesn't contain anymore previous rows, and I can only load them from database but it means that I can lose my changes already made to view object rows.

So, when I do

```
viewObject.setDoFiltering(false);
viewObject.setQueryMode(ViewObject.QUERY_MODE_SCAN_VIEW_ROWS);
viewObject.executeQuery();
```

It will return me those rows that were displayed previous time.
If I do

```
viewObject.setDoFiltering(true);
viewObject.setQueryMode(ViewObject.QUERY_MODE_SCAN_DATABASE_TABLES);
viewObject.executeQuery();
```

It will return me all rows, but I will lost my changes already made to view object rows.

My questions is how to avoid it? Maybe there is another way of doing this? Maybe it is possible to do something with RichTable to tell it how to filter rows in memory.

Any advices are warmly appricated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be done using ViewCriteria, to filter means to apply a ViewCriteria, and then disable it to view all your data